# .NET Core 3.1 - Angular 9 - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect

I do a publish of my web site on a IIS instance on a windows machine

```
publish myporject.dev.csproj --configuration Release --output "...my site folder"
```

problem : **the site returns ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

I tried : adding middlewares to avoid looping redirects but it does not work

In my angular frontend startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        options.KnownProxies.Clear();
    });
    services.AddHttpsRedirection(opt => opt.HttpsPort = 443);

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });
}
```

here is how my app is configured

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect("index.html", "/"));

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    if (!env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
        // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1000);
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

is there something I am missing ?

anyone already had the issue ?

thanks for helping me on this

Comment: Maybe it is caused by redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS.And maybe you can see `Try clearing your cookies`. in your page,you can clear your cookie and try again,it can also be caused by cookies in the browser caching old redirects.

Comment: there are no cookies, I already tried that...where do you see a redirection ? apart from the mandatory angular index.html redirect of course